# javadoc - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/docx4j/openpackaging/exceptions/Docx4JException

Tags: java, ant, apache-poi, javadoc, docx4j

I am trying to Run (using ANT) Javadoc on Source files to generate documentation (using custom doclet) in table format using docx4j (also tried with Apache POI, same error). I know the cause of error (Not finding class at runtime). I am getting console error as below after running ANT Build File. I am not sure why it is happening.

**Console Error**

```
javadoc:
  [javadoc] Generating Javadoc
  [javadoc] Javadoc execution
  [javadoc] 1 error
  [javadoc] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/docx4j/openpackaging/exceptions/Docx4JException
  [javadoc]     at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
  [javadoc]     at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
  [javadoc]     at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
  [javadoc]     at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
  [javadoc]     at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
  [javadoc]     at com.sun.tools.javadoc.DocletInvoker.invoke(DocletInvoker.java:286)
  [javadoc]     at com.sun.tools.javadoc.DocletInvoker.validOptions(DocletInvoker.java:238)
  [javadoc]     at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Start.parseAndExecute(Start.java:333)
  [javadoc]     at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Start.begin(Start.java:219)
  [javadoc]     at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Start.begin(Start.java:205)
  [javadoc]     at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Main.execute(Main.java:64)
  [javadoc]     at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Main.main(Main.java:54)
  [javadoc] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.docx4j.openpackaging.exceptions.Docx4JException
  [javadoc]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
  [javadoc]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
  [javadoc]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
  [javadoc]     ... 12 more
  [javadoc] javadoc: error - fatal error
```

Following are the files I am working on

**build.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project default="all">

    <target name="all" depends="show, compile, javadoc">
    </target>

    <property environment="env" />
    <property file="build.properties" />

    <path id="master-classpath">
        <fileset dir="lib">
            <include name="*.jar" />
        </fileset>
    </path>

    <target name="compile">
        <mkdir dir="build/classes" />

        <javac srcdir="src" destdir="build/classes">
            <classpath>
                <path refid="master-classpath" />
            </classpath>
        </javac>
    </target>

    <target name="show">
        <echo message="${toString:master-classpath}" />
    </target>

    <target name="javadoc">
        <javadoc access="private" useexternalfile="yes">
            <fileset dir="${cr.srcpath}" />
            <doclet name="com.my.tdd.util.CommentReader" path="build\classes" />
            <classpath>
                <path refid="master-classpath" />
            </classpath>
        </javadoc>
    </target>
</project>
```

**CommentReader.java**

```
package com.my.tdd.util;

import java.io.File;

import org.docx4j.openpackaging.exceptions.Docx4JException;
import org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.WordprocessingMLPackage;
import org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.WordprocessingML.MainDocumentPart;

import com.sun.javadoc.ClassDoc;
import com.sun.javadoc.MethodDoc;
import com.sun.javadoc.Parameter;
import com.sun.javadoc.RootDoc;

public class CommentReader {
    public static boolean start(RootDoc root) throws Docx4JException {

        // Just trying to generate simple docx file
        WordprocessingMLPackage wordPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.createPackage();
        MainDocumentPart mainDocumentPart = wordPackage.getMainDocumentPart();
        mainDocumentPart.addStyledParagraphOfText("Title", "Hello World!");
        mainDocumentPart.addParagraphOfText("Welcome To Baeldung");
        File exportFile = new File("welcome.docx");
        wordPackage.save(exportFile);

        // Table Generation and Other Logic

        return true;
    }
}
```

**/lib**

[image]

**Buildpath**

[image]

I have scanned StackOverflow for this question, but couldn't find solution.

Comment: In one part of your ant file you have build\classes, in another build/classes.  That doesn't look right?  In master-classpath, lib is relative.  Check it.

Answer (score 0):

I used similar code :

```
public class Doc4jData {

public static void main (String a[]) throws  Exception
{

    WordprocessingMLPackage wordPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.createPackage();
    MainDocumentPart mainDocumentPart = wordPackage.getMainDocumentPart();
    mainDocumentPart.addStyledParagraphOfText("Title", "Hello World!");
    mainDocumentPart.addParagraphOfText("Welcome Shashank");
    File exportFile = new File("welcome.docx");
    wordPackage.save(exportFile);
}
```

I used Spring Boot , just make sure to use dependencies :

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.docx4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>docx4j</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

I am successfully able to generate a word file named "welcome"

[image]